# GenAI-powered GUI-based image processor (Photoshop style)

Tags: image-processing, artificial-intelligence

I have been looking for a GenAI-powered image processor that would ideally be able to take prompts such as "crop this image to the shape of a wrapped lollipop, with three-pixel feathering"; or "blur the grass background from this portrait while maintaining the foliage of the trees in focus".

In other words, a freely available online tool that can accomplish complex tasks that normally would require a very skilled user of Photoshop or similar software.

I'm aware of AI-powered (text-to-image) generators, but I hope it's clear from the above that what I seek is different. This includes Adobe Firefly, which seems to be about image generation as opposed to image editing.

Googling didn't reveal any relevant free off-the-shelf tools, so I'm hoping someone can recommend something.

It could well be that no such (free) tool exists yet, although if so, presumably said tool is not far into the future.

One online (in-browser) tool I found, but haven't tried as it requires a paid subscription without a free trial, is Luminar. Pixlr is free but its editing capabilities don't seem beyond what older versions of Photoshop offer, i.e. not GenAI-powered.

Answer (score 0):

**StableDiffusion** is an open-source Generative AI model developed by Stability AI. It is designed to generate high-quality images from textual descriptions and can be run locally on your personal computer.
. To **run an older version of StableDiffusion locally**, you need a powerful computer with a compatible GPU and enough resources. Then follow several steps:

- Install Python: > python3.82 seems to be required, Create a Conda Environment
  .
- Clone the Stable Diffusion Repository: [`git clone https://github.com/CompVis/stable-diffusion.git`](https://github.com/CompVis/stable-diffusion.git).  Maybe there is a newer repo available.
  .
- Download the Weights See [blog post](https://www.assemblyai.com/blog/how-to-run-stable-diffusion-locally-to-generate-images/) by AssemblyAI
- Run the Model: Once you have completed the above steps, you can run Stable Diffusion using the command `python demo.py --prompt "your text prompt here"`. The inference time will be high at around 8-12 minutes
  .

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I am unfortunately unable to run this software through python right now, and was in fact looking for a GUI solution. Sorry if I wasn't clear.